# Where can we create queries in Kibana dashboard

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kql

If we need to create queries in Kibana dashboard without creating any codebase change where can we do it. Is there any place to create queries in Kibana. Please tell me anyone who knows that place. Because I have a big problem in our project, creating a dashboard for the logs.

Answer (score 0):

see either https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/kuery-query.html or https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/lucene-query.html

and https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/save-load-delete-query.html may also be relevant